# java.base missing while trying jlink

Tags: java, macos, java-9, jlink

I am getting this `Error: Module java.base not found` while trying to use jlink.

These are the 2 things I have tried so far

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink --module-path "%JAVA_HOME%\jmods":mods --add-modules com.tutorialspoint.greetings,java.base --output customjre
Error: Module java.base not found

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink --module-path "%JAVA_HOME%\jmods":mods --add-modules com.tutorialspoint.greetings,java.base@9.0.4 --output customjre
Error: Module java.base@9.0.4 not found
```

My module contains this.

```
module com.tutorialspoint.greetings { 
    requires java.base;
}
```

I followed this tutorial for making modules exactly except I added the requires java.basic.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java9/java9_module_system.htm

I tried it without requires java.base and still get the same problem.
Any ideas? I am new to JLink and Java9 and wanted to try it since java8 doesn't have Jlink.

Maybe it's how I am referencing to JLink in the directory itself?

Comment: try using an absolute path to the JDK's default jmods instead of `%JAVA_HOME%\jmods` for your module-path with the first command. By the way, you don't really need to explicitly mention the `requires java.base;` directive.

Comment: Thanks @Naman I didn't think about the JAVA_HOME path being wrong. Yeah I tried it with and without the requires java.base with no luck. Let me try that JAVA_HOME change.

Comment: @Naman 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink --module-path "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home\jmod":mods --add-modules com.tutorialspoint.greetings --output customjre
Error: Module java.base not found, required by com.tutorialspoint.greetings

Still no luck. Note that I did also change jmods to jmod since it appears thats what it is called.

Comment: It is interesting the error has changed slightly. It now says "required by com.tutorialspoint.greetings"

Comment: I just tired the exact command (changed for windows ; instead of :) and it worked. Not sure why it was broken on mac.

Comment: I’m very sure that the Windows syntax `%JAVA_HOME%` does not work on MacOS. Depending on the shell, it would be something like `${JAVA_HOME}`. Also, don’t use backslash as separator, as in `\jmods`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that the path of the module is poorly defined.

If you are on macos, the correct syntax is:

```
jlink --module-path "mods:$JAVA_HOME/jmods" --add-modules com.tutorialspoint.greetings --output customjre
```

Make sure the `JAVA_HOME` variable is set before running the `jlink`.

Also, it is not necessary to define the requires clause with the `java.base` module in your module because the `java.base` module is implicitly added in all modules.