# Error: Module java.base not found, required by while trying jlink on Fedora

Tags: linux, maven, javafx, java-11, jlink

When trying to use jlink on Fedora from this plugin https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin

```
<groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.0.8</version>
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.alcamech</groupId>
    <artifactId>jomo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jomo</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <compress>2</compress>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <launcher>jomo</launcher>
                            <mainClass>com.alcamech.jomo/com.alcamech.jomo.Jomo</mainClass>
                            <jlinkImageName>jomo</jlinkImageName>
                            <jlinkZipName>jomo</jlinkZipName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

module-info.java

```
module com.alcamech.jomo {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.media;

    opens com.alcamech.jomo to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.alcamech.jomo;
}
```

I get the following error
`Error: Module java.base not found, required by com.alcamech.jomo`

Running `java --list-modules` returns.

```
java.base@11.0.13
java.compiler@11.0.13
java.datatransfer@11.0.13
java.desktop@11.0.13
java.instrument@11.0.13
java.logging@11.0.13
java.management@11.0.13
java.management.rmi@11.0.13
java.naming@11.0.13
java.net.http@11.0.13
java.prefs@11.0.13
java.rmi@11.0.13
java.scripting@11.0.13
java.se@11.0.13
java.security.jgss@11.0.13
java.security.sasl@11.0.13
java.smartcardio@11.0.13
java.sql@11.0.13
java.sql.rowset@11.0.13
java.transaction.xa@11.0.13
java.xml@11.0.13
java.xml.crypto@11.0.13
jdk.accessibility@11.0.13
jdk.aot@11.0.13
jdk.attach@11.0.13
jdk.charsets@11.0.13
jdk.compiler@11.0.13
jdk.crypto.cryptoki@11.0.13
jdk.crypto.ec@11.0.13
jdk.dynalink@11.0.13
jdk.editpad@11.0.13
jdk.hotspot.agent@11.0.13
jdk.httpserver@11.0.13
jdk.internal.ed@11.0.13
jdk.internal.jvmstat@11.0.13
jdk.internal.le@11.0.13
jdk.internal.opt@11.0.13
jdk.internal.vm.ci@11.0.13
jdk.internal.vm.compiler@11.0.13
jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management@11.0.13
jdk.jartool@11.0.13
jdk.javadoc@11.0.13
jdk.jcmd@11.0.13
jdk.jconsole@11.0.13
jdk.jdeps@11.0.13
jdk.jdi@11.0.13
jdk.jdwp.agent@11.0.13
jdk.jfr@11.0.13
jdk.jlink@11.0.13
jdk.jshell@11.0.13
jdk.jsobject@11.0.13
jdk.jstatd@11.0.13
jdk.localedata@11.0.13
jdk.management@11.0.13
jdk.management.agent@11.0.13
jdk.management.jfr@11.0.13
jdk.naming.dns@11.0.13
jdk.naming.ldap@11.0.13
jdk.naming.rmi@11.0.13
jdk.net@11.0.13
jdk.pack@11.0.13
jdk.rmic@11.0.13
jdk.scripting.nashorn@11.0.13
jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell@11.0.13
jdk.sctp@11.0.13
jdk.security.auth@11.0.13
jdk.security.jgss@11.0.13
jdk.unsupported@11.0.13
jdk.unsupported.desktop@11.0.13
jdk.xml.dom@11.0.13
jdk.zipfs@11.0.13
```

Currently on

```
Fedora release 35 (Thirty Five), 5.15.13-200.fc35.x86_64

openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I got this error while also following the sample project(Modular Intellij, Modular CLI) from https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/. Cloning my project repo on windows and running the jlink command is successful. I've tried the jlink command through the CLI on linux and got the same error. I've opened a github issue with a full maven log here https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/146

Debug jlink command line from mvn javafx:link output:

```
[DEBUG] Executing command line: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin/jlink, --module-path, /home/alcamech/Development/jomo/target/classes:/home/alcamech/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/17.0.0.1/javafx-base-17.0.0.1-linux.jar:/home/alcamech/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/17.0.0.1/javafx-controls-17.0.0.1-linux.jar:/home/alcamech/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/17.0.0.1/javafx-fxml-17.0.0.1-linux.jar:/home/alcamech/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/17.0.0.1/javafx-graphics-17.0.0.1-linux.jar:/home/alcamech/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-media/17.0.0.1/javafx-media-17.0.0.1-linux.jar, --add-modules, com.alcamech.jomo, --output, /home/alcamech/Development/jomo/target/image, --compress, 0]
```

Comment: Provide the pom.xml and perhaps code for a [mcve], though I guess it should replicate for a simple standard helloworld app, so probably just the pom.xml is sufficient.  Check the JAVA_HOME environment variable and path settings are correct for the machine where the linking is failing.

Comment: Edit the question to include the full debug output, formatted as code, so that it isn't only on an external site.

Comment: Add the module-info.java file that you are using to your quesition.

Comment: I edited your question to add the debug output for linking used by the mvn javafx:jlink target.  Try to execute the command in the debug statement from the command line to see if it works there.

Comment: Note, usually module issues with javafx are in not finding the JavaFX modules, but in this case it [cannot find the `java.base` module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452569/java-base-missing-while-trying-jlink), with is a JDK module, so that means that the path used to access the JDK modules for the jlink command is incorrect.

Comment: I'm guess it is that `JAVA_HOME` is undefined, see the [jlink documentation for `-p` or `--module-path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jlink.html) -> "If this option is not specified, then the default module path is $JAVA_HOME/jmods. This directory contains the java.base module and the other standard and JDK modules. If this option is specified but the java.base module cannot be resolved from it, then the jlink command appends $JAVA_HOME/jmods to the module path.".

Comment: If it is an issue with `JAVA_HOME` being undefined, ask that the `javafx-maven-plugin` developers update the [readme](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md) to make it clear that this environment variable should be correctly defined for the linking process to work, also, perhaps, the javafx-maven-plugin should log a warning if a relevant java module path cannot be found.

Comment: Although Java 11 should work, I'd advise upgrading to Java 17+

Comment: @jewelsea JAVA_HOME is valid echo results in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.13.0.8-2.fc35.x86_64/` module-info.java added.

Comment: What is in the location `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.13.0.8-2.fc35.x86_64/`, is it a full JDK or is it just a JRE?  Are the required modules in the `$JAVA_HOME/jmods` directory?  Is the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable value available to the the openjfx-maven-plugin when you execute it?

Comment: @jewelsea It is a full JDK directory. I have this in my `.bashrc` `export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink $(readlink $(which javac)))))` I've also added `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

Comment: The maven debug output in the issue you followed for the plugin says `env.JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk`, which is different from what you posted in comments, though perhaps you have a symlink or something setup to make it work I guess.

Comment: @jewelsea This is configured from intellij. I'l' change it to the correct path. Running javafx:jlink now uses `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.13.0.8-2.fc35.x86_64/bin/java` Still the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241189/discussion-between-alcamech-and-jewelsea).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am missing the jmods directory in my jdk. On Fedora jmods are a separate install
`https://fedora.pkgs.org/35/fedora-x86_64/java-11-openjdk-jmods-11.0.12.0.7-4.fc35.x86_64.rpm.html`

Run `sudo dnf install java-11-openjdk-jmods`