# beryx runtime plugin fails at 'jre' task for JavaFX project: module javafx.base not found despite modules declared in 'javafx' block

Tags: javafx, packaging

I'm attempting to update a JavaFX app after quite a number of years and am stuck at trying to package it for distribution. The app runs just fine from an Eclipse launch config, but using Gradle and the beryx runtime plugin fail to produce a package (dmg in particular), failing at the invocation of the `jre` task.

This is a large, **non-modular** JavaFX-based project (hence use of **`org.beryx.runtime`**, see the `plugins` block below).

Details:

- Gradle Version: 8.1.1
- jdk-19.0.2.jdk

and the relevant blocks from `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.14'
    id "org.kordamp.gradle.jdeps" version "0.12.0"
    id 'org.beryx.runtime' version '1.12.5'
}
...
ext {
    javaFxVersion = '17.0.7'

    jfxModules = [
        'javafx.base',
        'javafx.controls',
        'javafx.fxml',
        'javafx.media',
        'javafx.web',
        'javafx.swing'
    ]
    ...
}
...
dependencies {
    implementation ('org.openjfx:javafx-controls:$javaFxVersion')
    implementation ('org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:$javaFxVersion')
    implementation ('org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:$javaFxVersion')
    implementation ('org.openjfx:javafx-base:$javaFxVersion')
    implementation ('org.openjfx:javafx-web:$javaFxVersion')

    implementation ("org.controlsfx:controlsfx:$controlsfxVersion") {
        exclude group: 'org.openjfx'
    }
    ... // many others not related to JavaFX
}
...
javafx {
    version = javaFxVersion
    modules = jfxModules
}
...
runtime {

    options = [ '--verbose', '--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages' ]

    modules = jfxModules

    jpackage {
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Executing any beryx **runtime plugin** task that invokes the `jre` task (e.g., `runtime`, `jpackage`, `jpackageImage`) results in the following error:

```
taskData: org.beryx.runtime.data.JreTaskData(jreDir:/Users/pf/workspace/myproject/build/jre, options:[--verbose, --strip-debug, --compress, 2, --no-header-files, --no-man-pages], additive:false, modules:[javafx.base, javafx.controls, javafx.fxml, javafx.media, javafx.web, javafx.swing], javaHome:/Users/pf/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home, targetPlatforms:[:])

Executing: [/Users/pf/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink, -v, --verbose, --strip-debug, --compress, 2, --no-header-files, --no-man-pages, --module-path, /Users/pf/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/jmods/, --add-modules, javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media,javafx.web,javafx.swing, --output, /Users/pf/workspace/myproject/build/jre]

Starting process 'command '/Users/pf/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink''. Working directory: /Users/pf/workspace/myproject Command: /Users/pf/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink -v --verbose --strip-debug --compress 2 --no-header-files --no-man-pages --module-path /Users/pf/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/jmods/ --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media,javafx.web,javafx.swing --output /Users/pf/workspace/myproject/build/jre

Successfully started process 'command '/Users/pf/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink''

Error: Module javafx.base not found
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:892)
    . . .
```

Comment: The debug line is showing the jlink command being run.  Run that from the command line.  See what happens.  If it is failing in the same way, then there is an issue with the generated jlink command.  Consult the jlink documentation to try to troubleshoot what that is.  Perhaps it is [this (missing jmod files in your JDK distribution)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70763967/1155209)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Since my app is non-modular, I'm using the org.beryx.runtime plugin. When the `jpackage` task, these are the tasks to be executed: `[task ':compileJava', task ':processResources', task ':classes', task ':jar', task ':startScripts', task ':installDist', task ':jre', task ':jpackageImage', task ':jpackage']`. `jre` is invoked instead of `jlink` in badass-runtime plugin's task chain. Attempting to include a `jlink` script block causes an error. This is becoming a nightmare: now their own example doesn't produce a viable app. The wrong architecture is being bundled!

Comment: Read the log line you yourself posted: *"Starting process 'command '/Users/pf/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink''. Working directory: /Users/pf/workspace/myproject Command: `/Users/pf/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink -v --verbose --strip-debug --compress 2 --no-header-files --no-man-pages --module-path /Users/pf/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/jmods/ --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media,javafx.web,javafx.swing --output /Users/pf/workspace/myproject/build/jre`"*.  That is calling `jlink`.

Comment: What is happening (I think) is the `jre` task you refer to is the beryx runtime plugin invoking `jlink` to build a custom `jre` which I guess is then to used is subsequent steps.  What I am suggesting is to verify that you have a well-formed `jre` for the custom `jre` created by the `jlink` command that was invoked by the beryx plugin.  It may be that that step is fine and the issues are solely in subsequent steps (I don't know), but the verification is something you can do independently.  Also, if the architecture involved here is wrong, it won't work (as I guess you already know).